# If $G/H$ is flat $A$-module, and $I$ is an ideal of $A$, $G$ is flat, then how to see $GI\cap H=HI$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

If $G/H$ is a flat $A$-module, and $I$ is a finitely generated ideal of $A$, $G$ is a flat $A$-module, $H$ is an $A$-submodule of $G$, then how to see $GI\cap H=HI$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a general fact that given an exact sequence
$$
0\rightarrow M\hookrightarrow F\rightarrow N\rightarrow 0
$$
of (right) $A$-modules with $F$ flat, then $N$ is flat iff $M\cap FI=MI$ for every finitely generated (left) ideal $I$. The proof is a bit involved, but it can be found as Proposition 3.60 of Rotman's *Introduction to Homological Algebra,* (page 139, in my copy at least.)

This applies to your situation, as you have an exact sequence
$$
0\rightarrow H\hookrightarrow G\rightarrow G/H\rightarrow 0,
$$
where $G$ is a flat $A$-module. Since $G/H$ is given to be flat, one direction of the above fact gives you the desired conclusion.